# Why is this a parse error in do notation?

Tags: haskell, syntax, parse-error, let, do-notation

Consider the following code:

```
foo = do
  let bar = do
    baz
  bar
```

It doesn't parse in `ghc`, version 8. It complains about the line containing `baz`. This code does parse, though:

```
foo = do
  let bar = do
      baz
  bar
```

I find this confusing. What's the essential difference between the two versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the indentation puts `baz` in no-mans land. It isn't indented far enough to be part of the `let` expression, but it is indented too far to be the next part of the `do` expression containing the `let` expression.

Comment: Why are two spaces not enough to make it part of the `do` block? Note that it's not directly part of the `let`, since no value is assigned to it.

Comment: @Turion Haskell’s layout rules require that everything on the RHS of a `let` or `where` be indented *at least* as far as the first column of the pattern on the LHS. In your first example, `baz` isn’t indented as far as `bar`, which is not okay, but in the second example it is.